# how can I change Forms Skinable into entire application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have application with 302 Forms that I want to change program graphic with devexpress,I want to change my forms into Skinable
without change manually,I mean its possible to change forms Skinable or change to regular form with code ??that apply entire application ???

Comment: Consider editing your question to include an example of the code that you want changed. This should help to get more answers for your question.

Comment: Ok thank,sure I will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a global find-and-replace to swich the System.Windows.Forms.Form in each form class with the DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm class so that each form derives from it.

For instance, what may have previously been:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
```

Would now be:

```
frmLogin : XtraForm
```

That will ensure your forms are skinnable. After that, I would add a [DefaultLookAndFeel component](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.LookAndFeel.DefaultLookAndFeel) to your main form to act as the central control for all the sub-forms. You can set the static global Default look and feel property to set the skin globally:

```
DevExpress.LookAndFeel.UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("The Bezier");
```

See also: [How to: Customize Look And Feel of All Controls within Application](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2412/common-features/application-appearance-and-skin-colors/look-and-feel/how-to-customize-look-and-feel-of-all-controls-within-application)